# Show an open set has no minimum

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $A$ is an open subset of the real numbers. How to prove $A$ has no minimum?

I guess it should be done with Proof-by-contradiction, but I don't get anywhere at this point.

Comment: Hint: If $A$ is open and $x\in A$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq A$. In particular, then, $x-\delta/2\in A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $m \in A$ is the minimum of A. By definition of open set, you have that $(m-\delta , m + \delta) \subseteq A$ with $\delta > 0$ sufficiently small, then $m- \frac{\delta}{2} \in A$ but this is a contradiction (because we have found an element in A smaller than $m$)

Comment: Thanks David and Ella, it's very clear. :)