# Find for given upper-bound, epsilon.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Need help in vetting my answers for Q. 3,4,5 in section 2.2.2 in chap. *[2 (page 7)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=w5xE8mpZ4VoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)* in CRM series book by MAA: Exploratory Examples for Real Analysis, By Joanne E. Snow, Kirk E. Weller. Also, this post is in continuation of my [last post's question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3213514/424260). [image: here]

> **3.** For each set in Table 2.2, select an upper bound $u$ i.e. *not* equal to the supremum. Enter this value in column 2. For each $\epsilon$ given in columns 3,4, and 5, determine whether there are elements of the set that fall in the half-open interval $(u - \epsilon, u]$. If so, enter 'yes' in the appropriate cell of the table, & then describe all such elements of the set that satisfy this condition. If there are no such elements, enter ''no' in the table, & provide an explanation as to why this might be the case.
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
>  Set & \text{$u$} & \text{$\epsilon=.5$} & \text{$\epsilon=.1$} & \text{$\epsilon=.05$} & \text{$Q\, 4$} \\ \hline
>  S_2 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: 0\le x \lt 1 \}  & 1.001 & (.501,1] & (0.901,1] & (0.951,1] & Yes \\ & & & & &(\forall u | u-s \ge \epsilon) \\ \hline
> S_3 = \{(-1)^n(2+\frac 1n)\,: n\in \mathbb{N}\}  & 2.51 & \{2.01,\cdots,2.5\} & \{2.5\} & \{2.5\}  & --do--\\ \hline
> S_4 = \{arctan(x)\,: x\in \mathbb{R}\}  & \frac \pi{2} + 0.1 & (\frac \pi{2} - 0.4, \frac \pi{2}) & no & no & --do-- \\ \hline
> S_5 = \{(-1)^n\,:  n\in \mathbb{N}\}  & 1.2 & \{1\} & no & no & --do-- \\ \hline
> \end{array}$$

The columns under $\epsilon=0.5, 0.1, 0.05$ headings are found below:

> $S_2 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: 0\le x \lt 1 \} $ : $s=1$, let $u=1.001$.

**>$\epsilon=.5$ :** Desired interval is $(.501,1.001]$. The elements of set $S_1$ in interval are in $(.501,1.001]\cap S_1 = (.501,1)$.

**>$\epsilon=.1$ :** Desired interval is $(.901,1.001]$. The elements of set $S_1$ in interval are in $(.901,1.001]\cap S_1 = (.901,1)$.

**>$\epsilon=.05$ :** Desired interval is $(.951,1.001]$. The elements of set $S_1$ in interval are in $(.951,1.001]\cap S_1 = (.951,1)$.

> $S_3 = \{(-1)^n(2+\frac 1n)\,: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ : $s=2.5$, let $u = 2.51$.

As shown in my [last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3213514/424260), $S_3=\{-3,-2.\overline{33},-2.2, -2.\overline{2.142857}, -2.\overline{1}, \cdots,2.25,2.1\overline{6},2.125,2.5\}$.
**>$\epsilon=.5$ :** Want to obtain the first term in the series for which get value $\ge 2.01$. Will check if get an element of the $S_3$ at the lower bound of the interval.

$2.01 = 2 + \frac 1n\implies .01n=1\implies n = 100$
Putting $n=100$, in $(-1)^n(2+\frac 1n)$ get $(-1)^{100}(2+\frac 1{100})\implies \frac {201}{100}= 2.01$.
Hence, the set is having element at the lower bound, but not included as open bound there.

**>$\epsilon=.1$ :** Want to obtain the first term in the series for which get value $\ge 2.41$.

$2.41 = 2 + \frac 1n\implies .41n=1\implies n = \frac{100}{41} \approx 2.43$. 
Rounding off, get the nearest $n=2$.
$n=2$ is for supremum $=2.5 \gt 2.43$.
Hence, only one element $s$ is there.

**>$\epsilon=.05$ :**  Want to obtain the first term in the series for which get value $\ge 2.46$.

$2.46 = 2 + \frac 1n\implies .46n=1\implies n = \frac{100}{46} \approx 2.17$.
 Rounding off, get the nearest $n=2$.
$n=2$ is for supremum $=2.5 \gt 2.43$.
Hence, only one element $s$ is there.

> $S_4 = \{arctan(x)\,: x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ :

Let, $u=\frac \pi{2} + 0.001$.
Note: The supremum value ($s$) is an irrational quantity. However, it is assumed to be attained for $x\rightarrow \infty$. For measurable values of $x$, $s$ is not attained.

**>$\epsilon=.5$ :** The range of interval is: $((\frac{\pi}2-0.4), \frac{\pi}2]$. The supremum is not in the range, but any value below $s$ should be. Also, taking $\tan((\frac \pi{2}+0.1) - 0.4 \approx 1.1707963267948966192313216916398)$ get measure as $49.49871336^o$. So, all reals in the interval $((\frac{\pi}2-0.4), \frac{\pi}2)$ are there.

**>$\epsilon=.1$ :** The range of interval is: $(\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2+0.1]$. Due to the supremum not being in the range, no element of set $S_4$ in the interval.  
Note that $\epsilon (=.1)$ is the same as the difference between $u,s$, i.e. $u-s=0.1$.

**>$\epsilon=.05$ :** The range of interval is: $(\frac{\pi}2+0.1 -\epsilon (=.05), \frac{\pi}2+0.1]$. But, the lower bound is bigger than $s$, leading to no element of set $S_4$ in the interval.

> $S_5 = \{(-1)^n\,:  n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ :

$s = 1$, let $u=1.2$.

**>$\epsilon=.5$ :** The range of interval is: $(0.7, 2]$. The values of set in interval are $\{1\}$.

**>$\epsilon=.1$ :** The range of interval is: $(1.1, 2]$, i.e no values of set lie in interval.

**>$\epsilon=.05$ :** The range of interval is: $(1.05, 2]$, i.e no values of set lie in interval.

> **4.** For any upper bound $u$ that is *not* the supremum, does it seem possible, based on the data in Table 2.2, to find an $\epsilon\gt 0$ for which no elements of the given set lie in $(u - \epsilon, u]$? If so, enter yes in column 6 (under $Q 2$) and describe all such $\epsilon$. If not, enter no in column 6. In either case, explain your results.

Yes, if $u-s \ge \epsilon$, then no element of set is in the desired interval, as even the supremum (even, if in range) will be not in the open lower bound.

> **5.** Compare and contrast your findings for the supremum & an arbitrarily chosen upper bound. In particular, does there appear to be a difference in behavior between the supremum and an arbitrary chosen upper bound, as it relates to the issue of whether we can find elements of the set $S_i\,(i=2,3,4,5)$ in the interval $(s - \epsilon, s]$ for any value of $\epsilon \gt 0$?

The value of $\epsilon$ was not so important in the case of finding any element of the respective set $S_i\,(i=2,3,4,5)$  in the interval $(s-\epsilon, s]$, as $\epsilon\gt 0$; leading always to getting, at least some value, in the worst case of the supremum not being in the set & there being discrete values in range.
But, now need $u-s\lt \epsilon$ as a must to have any element in the sets in the interval $(u-\epsilon, u]$.

Let us consider all sets below for showing the latter case:

> $S_2 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: 0\le x \lt 1 \} $ :

If $u-s \ge \epsilon$, say as $s=1$, if $u=s+1, \epsilon=0.1$, then no element of $S_2$ is in the interval $(1.9,2]$.

> $S_3 = \{(-1)^n(2+\frac 1n)\,: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ :

As shown in my [last post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3213514/424260), $S_3=\{-3,-2.\overline{33},-2.2, -2.\overline{2.142857}, -2.\overline{1}, \cdots,2.25,2.1\overline{6},2.125,2.5\}$.
If $u-s \ge \epsilon$, say as $s=2.5$, if $u = 2.9, \epsilon = 0.1$, then no element of $S_3$ is in the interval.
Also, if $u-s \lt \epsilon$, say as $s=2.5$, then possible to have elements of the set in the interval. Say, if $u = 2.625, \epsilon = 0.5$, then the element of $S_3$ in the interval are in set $\{2.125,2.5\}$.

> $S_4 = \{arctan(x)\,: x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ :

Let $u=\frac \pi{2} + k.\epsilon, k\gt 1$. Here, no value of set is in the interval $(\frac \pi{2} + (k-1).\epsilon, \frac \pi{2} + k.\epsilon]$.

> $S_5 = \{(-1)^n\,:  n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ :

Let $u=1+ k.\epsilon, k\gt 1$. Here, no value of set is in the interval $(1 + (k-1).\epsilon, 1+k.\epsilon]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Notice that $1 \notin S_2$, $(.501, 1.001] \cap S_2 = (0.501, 1).$
- $S_3$ consists of discrete points, the intersection can't be an interval.
- For question $4$, you might like to describe the set of $\epsilon$ explicitly.

Edit:

$$S_3 \cap (2.01, 2.51]=\{2+\frac1{2m}: 2+\frac1{2m}>2+\frac1{100}\}=\{2+\frac1{2m}: m< 50\}$$

Comment: Thanks, have edited for first two points. Please vet. But, the 3rd point is already implemented before & after the Q. 4, i.e. by taking $\epsilon$ values. So, feel for here, redundant.

Comment: Request to be in chatroom for Q. 2.4: 'Based on your answers to the prior questions, try to write "new" definition. This definition (let, Defn. 2) will involve a nonempty set $X$, a positive real $\epsilon$, & half-open interval $(s - \epsilon, s]$, where $s$ denotes supremum.'  ---MY atempt is: A nonempty set $X$ will have its range $\cap(s - \epsilon, s]\ne \emptyset, \,\, \forall \epsilon\gt 0$. ---But want to discuss my efforts at equivalence betn. conventional defn. (Defn. 1) & Defn. 2. Please chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93126/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten.

Comment: Request elaboration of the selected answer in my post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3217101/424260. Am unable to understand how to state an arbitrary set, i.e. bounded by defn..  I could not state there that it is part (b) of my earlier post at :https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3201755/424260.

Comment: Also, why your 'edit' here has chosen $\frac1{2m}$ rather than $\frac 1n$. Your choice might not work for odd values, say $101$.

Comment: because we know that odd terms are negative, which is not of our interest.

Comment: Please help in attempt on drawing equivalence betn. my new defn. (Defn. 2) of supremum (stated in my second comment) & usual lub based defn. (Defn.1). Need 2 sub-proofs: (a) given defn.1, arrive at defn. 2, (b) vice-versa. Attempt for (a) : Def. 1 implies: An upper bound $y\gt s$ will have set $X$ elements in $(y-\epsilon, y]$ if $y-s \lt \epsilon$. By proof: Let $y-s = k.\epsilon, 0\lt k\lt 1\implies y-s= k.\epsilon \implies y = s+k.\epsilon \implies y -\epsilon = s+(k-1).\epsilon \implies y-\epsilon \lt s$. New interval has even lower bound & higher upper bound in $(s+(k-1)\epsilon, y]$.

Comment: Please respond. Am eagerly waiting for a long time.

Comment: Have posted proof at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3217872/424260. Please help & vet.

Comment: Very busy day for me

Comment: Got no response for an much-effort-taking proof by me. If could spare some time, would be highly thankful. Else, would wait.