# Use derivative to find maxima, minima of the function : $n^\frac 1n: n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

This post is in ref. to my [earlier post's](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3201343/424260) row #10.

10. $\{n^\frac 1n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$: 
     Domain of values is in the set of naturals. 
    I am unable to find minimum, maximum (in range), and list a few values below:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|}   & \text{$n\in \mathbb{N}$}& \text{$n^{\frac1n}$}\\ \hline
a & 1& 1\\ \hline
b & 2& \sqrt{2}\\ \hline
c & 3& 3^{\frac13}\\ \hline
d & 4& 4^{\frac14}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The max. /min. value in range of function is unknown by me, hence it needs finding derivative (both first & second).
The eqn. would be :

$y = n^\frac 1n: n \in \mathbb{N}$, with steps to solve being in-complete:
$ \implies \ln y = \frac 1n \ln n \implies \frac 1y y' = \frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n ) \implies y' = n^\frac 1n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n )$

Need to double differentiate the above, but don't know how to pursue further.

---

*Edit:*

Based on the responses (comments, answers) have modified my attempt, that is still incomplete. Request vetting the contents also.:

As the function is exponential, so continuous one; but consider restricted domain of natural numbers, as given:

$y = n^\frac 1n: n \in \mathbb{N}$
As $\log$ is a monotonic function, so $\log y$ will be too.
$ \implies \ln y = \frac 1n \ln n \implies \frac 1y y' = \frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n ) \implies y' = n^\frac 1n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n )$

In $3$ product terms of $y' = n^\frac 1n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n )$, only last term $(1-\ln n)$ can reduce to $0$ for finite values, i.e. at $x=e$, as $\ln e = 1$.

First approach is to confirm that at $e$ if there is a maxima / minima, & need find by 2nd derivative.

Second approach (as shown in the selected answer) is to take value of fn. at integers surrounding $e$ at $x=2,3$, i.e. $3^{\frac13}, 2^{\frac12}$; it shows max. value at $x=e$.

Coming back to the first approach: 
if $y'$ max at $x=e$, then $y''$ is negative there, & vice versa. 
$ \implies \ln y = \frac 1n \ln n \implies \frac 1y y' = \frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n ) \implies y' = n^\frac 1n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n )$

Need to double differentiate the above.
$y' = n^\frac 1n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n) \implies \ln y' = \frac 1n \ln n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n)$

 Differentiating w.r.t. $n$ again:
$y'' = \frac{d}{dn}(y'.\frac 1n \ln n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n))\implies \frac{d}{dn}(n^\frac 1n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n).\frac 1n \ln n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n))$

Need help in completing finding the second derivative.

Comment: Careful..derivatives are only for continuous functions,not for integers..

Comment: Does the function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ has a zero in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya cannot say so. I request to provide answer considering the domain as reals, as the question is interesting in itself for real domain.

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya Please vet my edit (addendum) to the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We  have $1^{\frac11}=1$ and for any $n>1$, $n^\frac1n > 1$, the minimun and infimum is $1$.

Let $y = x^{\frac1x}$, $$\ln y = \frac{\ln x}{x}$$

$$\frac{d\ln y}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\ln x}{x}\right)= \frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$$

The value of $y$ increases when $\ln y$ increases. That is when $\frac{d\ln y}{dx}>0$, which is equivalent to $1-\ln x > 0$which is just  $\ln x < 1$, taking exponential both sides give us $x < e$.

Hence $y$ increases up to $e$ and then decreases.

Hence for any $x_1, x_2 \in (0,e)$ $x_1 < x_2$ implies that $x_1^{\frac1{x_1}}< x_2^{\frac1{x_2}}$.

For any $x_1, x_2 \in (e, \infty)$ $x_1 < x_2$ implies that $x_1^{\frac1{x_1}}> x_2^{\frac1{x_2}}$.

The only two possible value that could have attained the maximum values are $2$ and $3$.

Since $3^\frac13 > 2^\frac12$, the maximum and supremum is $3^\frac13$.

Remark:

- I am working with $\{ n^\frac1n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ which is a subset of the real number.
- I am not working with $\{ x^\frac1x: x \in \mathbb{R}, x>0 \}$.

Comment: so, I hope we are considering real domain. Please state this in answer, as helps later.

Comment: please elaborate your answer, as not clear how by looking at first derivative can ascertain that $y$ increases up to $e$ and then decreases. Sorry, for not seeing the edit regarding my last comment. Also, please state that how the domain is considered under naturals (as derivative is for continuous functions). Or it is the function whose continuity that matters, & not the domain. So, the values considered for $y$ are then for range in reals, irrespective of what the domain is.

Comment: Please look at my modified post. Please help in completing the second derivative part. Also, please vet the edited (addendum) part.

Comment: edited, we are not interested in computing the second derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Check the derivatives at n=2 and 3

(specifically at $2.718281828459045235360\cdots$)

Comment: yep the function $x^\frac{1}{x}$'s derivative vanishes at $e$ and at y where $y^\frac{1}{y}=0$

Comment: so are considering under real domain?

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya Please post an answer based on your all comments. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let f(x) = $x^{1/x}$.  Since $\log$ is monotonic, the function $\log(f(x))$ is increasing precisely where $f(x)$ is increasing.  Analyze the derivative of $\log (f(x))$ to see where the function is increasing and decreasing.  This sort of analysis will allow you to eliminate enough results so you can find the correct answer.

Comment: In $3$ product terms of $f'(x) = n^\frac 1n\frac 1{n^2}(1-\ln n )$, only last term $(1-\ln n)$ can reduce to $0$ for finite values, i.e. at $x=e$, as $\ln e = 1$. So, at $e$ there should be a maxima / minima, but need find by 2nd derivative. Other app. is to take value of fn. at integers surrounding $e$ at $x=2,3$, i.e. $3^{\frac13}, 2^{\frac12}$; it shows max. value at $x=e$. Coming to 1st app.: if $f'(x)$ max at $x=e$, then $f''(x)$ is negative there, & vice versa.

Comment: Have added all in my first comment, & more in Edit (addendum) to my post. Please vet & help complete that.

Comment: @jiten, you don't need to show $f''(e)<0$, instead show $f'(x)>0, 0<x<e$ and $f'(x)<0,x>e$, which implies $f(e)$ is maximum. It was implicitly stated in the accepted answer.