# Integration of sum of infinite geometric series.

Tags: real-analysis

It is given in CRM book, by MAA (A Radical Approach to Real Analysis By David M. Bressoud) in exercise of Q. 2.2.9 [image: Q. 2.2.9]

> It is tempting to integrate each side of eqn. (2.11) wrt $x$ and to assert that

The eqn. (2.11) is for sum of infinite geometric series as given by:

 $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots=\frac1{1-x}$, if $|x|\lt 1$.

> $x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^4}4+\cdot=-\ln(1-x).$ (2.13)
>
> Following [Cauchy's advice](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YSe4hUBM7uEC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=Following%20Cauchy%27s%20advice,%20we%20know%20we%20need%20to%20be%20careful.%20Differentiate%20each%20side%20of%20equation%20(2.10).%20What%20is%20the%20difference%20between&source=bl&ots=qoP8skujYI&sig=ACfU3U3jaTbedzOff_-FxZUY8cDRza1xXg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj08umUk_DhAhUJXisKHV2zCOYQ6AEwEnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) (on pg. 19), we know we need to be careful, but now we run into trouble.

This means that need take a finite lower bound on the number of terms ($n$). E.g., the eqn. (2.10) is for sum of geometric series, for a lower bound $n$ as given by: 
$1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{n-1}=\frac1{1-x} - \frac {x^n}{1-x}$, if $|x|\lt 1$.

> What happens when we try to integrate $\frac{x^n}{(1-x)}$?

Doubt 1: Not clear about it, as need to find integration using usual methods. But, if take it as a stand-alone problem, then how to pursue/ attack it.

> Fortunately, we do not have to find the exact value of the difference between $ x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\cdots+\frac{x^n}n$ and $-\ln(1-x)$. All we have to show is that we can make this difference as small as we wish by taking enough terms. We can do this by bounding the integral of $\frac{x^n}{(1-x)}$.

Need find bounds $a,b$ s.t. form limits for sum of enough terms, denoted by the difference $|b-a|$ 
$\int_a^b \frac{x^n}{(1-x)}dx$

> We use the fact that if
> $|f(x)|\lt g(x) $ for all x, then $|\int_a^b f(x)dx|\lt \int_a^b g(x)dx$.
>
>  If $0\lt x \lt 1$, then we can find a number $a$ so that $0\lt x\lt a\lt 1$ and 
> $|\frac{x^n}{1-x}| \lt x^n(1-a)^{-1}$

Doubt 2: Unable to see the significance of absolute value of limits of integrand obtained for $f(x)$. 
The inequality $|f(x)|\lt g(x)$ shows that for function $f(x)$ the negative values taken are also summed up. 
Is this a well-known result, if so what is its name?
Also, what is the significance of it here.

> Integrate this bounding function w.r.t. $x$, & show that if $0\lt x \lt 1$, then the partial sums of the series in eqn. (2.13) approach the target value of $-\ln(1-x)$ as $x$ increases.

Doubt 3:  Unable to pursue this computation. Need some clue.

> Explain what happens for $-1\lt x\lt 0$. Justify your answer.

Doubt 4: Unable to find the significance of such bounds.

Comment: Judging from this question alone, it appears that your book is good and you are lucky to have it. Most calculus textbooks don't deal with this issue.

Comment: The key is to analyze the integral $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^n}{1-t}\,dt$. If $0\leq x<1$ then we have $1/(1-t)<1/(1-x)$ for $0<t<x$. Thus the integral lies between $0$ and $x^{n+1}/((n+1)(1-x)) $ and this is less than $1/(n+1)(1-x)$ and so tends to $0$. You should do a similar analysis when $-1\leq x<0$ by putting $t=-u$ in integral.

Comment: I am in process of following your advice for Doubt #4, as based on your clue for  Doubt #3. But, am confused as how the term $\frac{x^n}{((n+1)(1-x))}$ came into picture from $|\frac{x^n}{1-x}| \lt x^n(1-a)^{-1}$. If could explain that, then understanding your clue & its appln. to Doubt #4 is easy. Also, request to supply answer (preferably) for Doubt #2. Also, as asked in there, is this a well known result?

Comment: First the absolute value signs are not necessarily as $x$ as well as $1-x$ are positive. The desired inequality as per my notation is $t^n/(1-t)<t^n(1-x)^{-1}$ and now integrate this inequality wrt $t$ and get desired result.

Comment: Please give some hint as directly integrating the below is not helping :  $|\frac{t^n}{1-t}| \lt t^n(1-x)^{-1} \implies |\frac{t^n}{(1-t)(1-x)}| \lt t^n$.

Taking the lhs, get: $\implies |\int_a^b \frac{x^n}{(1-x)(1-a)}|$, but this is not leading further. I am also scared of the comptn. I am feeling that here answer will help a lot.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Please respond to my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could have used the definition of incomplete Beta function

$$B(z; a,b) = \int_0^z u^{a-1}(1-u)^{b-1}\, du$$

to express

$$\int_0^{z}\frac{u^n}{1-u}\, du = \int_0^z u^{(n+1)-1}(1-u)^{-1}\, du = B(z; n+1, 0).$$

but if you don't understand the property of incomplete Beta function, it doesn't give you good control.

Also, for $|x| < 1$,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i = \frac1{1-x}- \frac{x^n}{1-x}$$

$$\int \frac{x^n}{1-x}\, dx = -\ln (1-x) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x^i}{i}+C$$

which is exactly the error term.

The message that the book is trying to send is you **don't** have to work with this quantity directly.

$$\int_{0}^x \frac{t^n}{1-t}\, dt = \int_0^x\left(\frac{1}{1-t}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}t^i \right)\, dt=-\ln (1-x) - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x^i}{i}$$

The error term is obtained by taking the absolute value,

$$\left| \int_{0}^x \frac{t^n}{1-t}\, dt\right|.$$

So our goal is to show that as $n$ is big enough, the error term shrink to zero.

Fixing a value of $x \in (0,1)$.

$$\left| \int_{0}^x \frac{t^n}{1-t}\, dt\right| \le \int_0^x \frac{t^n}{1-x} \, dt = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1-x)} \to 0$$

Fixing a value of $x \in (-1, 0)$,

$$\left| \int_{0}^x \frac{t^n}{1-t}\, dt\right| \le \int_x^0 |t|^n\, dt = \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}\to 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have never read about these special functions before. Please elaborate your answer for the last two lines as you have not shown values for $x,n, n+1, x^{n+1}, |x|^{n+1}$.

Comment: They are supposed to be general. There is no values to show.

Comment: For me it is impossible to understand the meaning of that (your last comment), might be unable to grasp the answer. Request chat.

Comment: If you prefer, let $x=0.5$ for the case when $x \in (0,1)$ and also let $x=-0.5$ for the case when $x \in (-1,0)$.

Comment: please refer to some literature or googling keywords for details on this problem. I tried for a lot of hours, but is like a dead end. Request to kindly accede to it, as you can by better knowledge. Without more literature, this question goes nowhere, by itself.

Comment: which particular step do you don't get it?

Comment: I want to understand problem first, i.e. how derived from $|\frac{x^n}{1-x}| \lt x^n(1-a)^{-1}$ with bounds $a,b$, where $n=|b-a|$ and $\int_a^b \frac{x^n}{(1-x)}dx$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93126/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten).

Comment: I will be awaiting your response in chat for any (or more) ways to help me: 1. elaboration by example, 2. desmos example, 3. literature ref.

Comment: From chat :  --  I was thinking that the "name" (as asked by me in Doubt #2) is 'comparison test' till your last response. But, was unsure only of the fact that this test needs comparison with a known function. This function should be here $g(x)=x^n(1-a)^{-1}$, which I am not sure is known (at least, by me).
Now your last comment comes - which seemingly breaks all about 'comparison test's applicability'. Unable to comprehend it, seems to me like stating - not to use the comparison test.

Comment: Please see my post on supremum based on epsilon at : 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3212192/424260