# Find for given supremum, epsilon.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Need help in vetting my answers for Q. 1,2 in section 2.2.2 in chap. *[2 (page 7)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=w5xE8mpZ4VoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)* in CRM series book by MAA: Exploratory Examples for Real Analysis, By Joanne E. Snow, Kirk E. Weller. [image: here].

> **Q. 1:**
>   For each set in Table 2.1, identify the supremum $s$ and enter your response in column 2. For each value of $\epsilon$ given in columns 3, 4, and 5, determine whether there are elements of the set that fall in the half-open interval $(s - \epsilon, s]$. If so, enter yes in the appropriate cell of the table, and then describe all such elements of the set that satisfy this condition. If there are no such elements, enter no in the table, & provide an explanation as to why this might be the case.
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
>  Set & \text{$s$} & \text{$\epsilon=.5$} & \text{$\epsilon=.1$} & \text{$\epsilon=.05$} & \text{$Q.\, 2$} \\ \hline
> \text 1)\,\ S_2 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: 0\le x \lt 1 \}  & 1 & yes & yes & yes &no\\ \hline
> \text 2)\,\ S_3 = \{(-1)^n(2+\frac 1n)\,: n\in \mathbb{N}\}  & 2.5 & yes & yes & yes &no \\ \hline
> \text 3)\,\ S_4 = \{arctan(x)\,: x\in \mathbb{R}\}  & \frac \pi{2} & yes & yes & yes &no\\ \hline
> \text 4)\,\ S_5 = \{(-1)^n\,:  n\in \mathbb{N}\}  & 1 & yes & yes & yes &no\\ \hline
> \end{array}$$

$S_2 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: 0\le x \lt 1 \}:$
$s :$ The upper open bound is the supremum. 
$\epsilon=.5 :(0.5, 1]$ : Yes, there are reals existing there. 
$\epsilon=.1 :(0.9, 1]$ : Yes, there are reals existing there. 
$\epsilon=.05 :(0.95, 1]$ : Yes, there are reals existing there.

$S_3 = \{(-1)^n(2+\frac 1n)\,: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$
$s :$ The function range alternates between positive & negative. The value $\frac 1n$ decreases with increasing $n$. So, the first positive value of $n=2$ yields the supremum $=2.5$. 
$\epsilon=.5 :(2, 2.5]$ : Set $S_3 $ lies in reals with supremum in the set.  <del>No natural exists in this interval.</del> 
$\epsilon=.1 :(2.4, 2.5]$ : ----same as above ---- 
$\epsilon=.05 :(2.45, 2.5]$ : ----same as above ----

$S_4 = \{arctan(x)\,: x\in \mathbb{R}\}$
$s :$ $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is the supremum. 
$\epsilon=.5 :(\frac{\pi}{2} - 0.5, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ : Yes, there are reals existing there. 
$\epsilon=.1 :(\frac{\pi}{2} - 0.1, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ : Yes, there are reals existing there. 
$\epsilon=.05 :(\frac{\pi}{2} - 0.05, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ : Yes, there are reals existing there.

$S_5 = \{(-1)^n\,:  n\in \mathbb{N}\}$
$s :1$
$\epsilon=.5 :(0.5, 1] $ : Yes, there is single natural in $S_5$ existing there, i.e $=1$. 
$\epsilon=.1 :(0.9, 1]$ : ----same as above ---- 
$\epsilon=.05 :(0.95, 1]$ : ----same as above ----

> **Q. 2.** For each set in Table 2.1, is it possible, based on the data you have entered, to find an $\epsilon\gt 0$ for which no elements of the given set lie in $(s - \epsilon, s]$? If so, enter yes in column 6 (under $Q.\, 2$) and describe all such $\epsilon$. If not, enter 'no' in column 6. In either case, explain your results.

The answers here are based on fact that $\epsilon$ is concerned with range, 
hence its domain is defined by range.

**>** $S_2 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: 0\le x \lt 1 \}:$
No, as only possible for $\epsilon=0$, or for 'the' real number just larger than $0$; which is not possible to find given the infinitude of reals between any two values.

*Edit :*
No, as only possible for $\epsilon=0$, as then the desired interval is : $(1,1]$; i.e. the point $=1$. But, this value of  $\epsilon=0$ is not permitted.

**>** $S_3 = \{(-1)^n(2+\frac 1n)\,: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$
Yes, for $\epsilon=2.5$.

*Edit :*
$$\begin{array}{c|c|} & \text{$n\in \mathbb{N}$}& \text{$\{(-1)^n(2+\frac 1n)\}$}\\ \hline
a & 1& -3 \\ \hline
b & 2& 2.5\\ \hline
c & 3& -\frac73=-2.\overline{33}\\ \hline
d & 4& \frac94= 2.25\\ \hline
d & 5& -\frac{11}5=-2.2\\ \hline
d & 6& \frac{13}{6}=2.1\overline{6}\\ \hline
d & 7& -\frac{15}{7}=-2.\overline{2.142857}\\ \hline
d & 8& \frac{17}{8}=2.125 \\ \hline
d & 9& -\frac{19}{9}=-2.\overline{1}\\ \hline
\cdots
\end{array}$$

$S_3=\{-3,-2.\overline{33},-2.2, -2.\overline{2.142857}, -2.\overline{1},\cdots,2.25,2.1\overline{6},2.125,2.5\}$ leading to no single value of $\epsilon\gt 0$ that enables no values of the set in given range of $(2.5-\epsilon, 2.5]$.

Say, take $\epsilon=0.1$. The desired range of values in which no value of set $S_3$ should fall is : $(2.5-0.1, 2.5]= (2.4, 2.5]$. 
But, this is false, as at least one value of $s$ lies in this closed interval.

If the interval $(s - \epsilon, s]$ is a valid one, then at least would be having $s$.

**>** $S_4 = \{arctan(x)\,: x\in \mathbb{R}\}$
Yes, for $\epsilon=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

*Edit :*
$S_4=(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ leading to no single value of $\epsilon$ that enables no values of the set to lie in  given interval $(\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon , \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

**>** $S_5 = \{(-1)^n\,:  n\in \mathbb{N}\}$
No, as then need only one value of $\epsilon=0$.

*Edit :*
$S_5 = \{-1,1\}$ & the interval is $(1 - \epsilon, 1]$. This leads to any value of $0\lt \epsilon\lt 1$ to not satisfy the requirement that no value of the set to lie in the interval. A value of $0\lt \epsilon\ge 1$ will also not satisfy the requirement, as the lower bound is negative, leading to possibly both points in the set to lie in the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find your $s$ correctly. Columns $3$ to $5$ must be yes and the last column must be no from definition of supremum.

For $S_3$, the supremum is $2.5 \in S_3$. Hence $s \in (s-\epsilon, s]$. Notice that the elements of the sets need not be natural number.

For $S_4$, if you pick $\epsilon = \frac{\pi}2$. We have $\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}4 \in S_4$. Hence you didn't fill in the last column correctly.

Note that $\color{red}{S_5=\{-1,1\}}$. The supremum is $1$.

Response to your edit:

- For $S_i$, rather than there are real numbers in the interval, the real interest is there are elements of $S_i$ in the interval.
- For $S_5$, the supremum is $1$, not $\infty$.  $S_5=\{1,-1\}$. The statement there are natural number existing there makes no sense.
- Also, domain and range are usually terminology associated with function.
- Question $2$ shouldn't be addressed individually:

What you need to argue for question $2$ is suppose on the contrary that such $\epsilon >0$ exists such that $(s-\epsilon, s] \cap S_i = \emptyset$, show that $s-\epsilon$ is an upperbound of $S_i$ as well which leads to a contradiction that $s$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have edited the post thoroughly.

Comment: Request to be in chatroom(https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93126/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten)  (better here only, as latex is converted here) for properties of arctan(x), as need to know if arctan $(\frac \pi{2} - 0.4 = 1.1707963267948966192313216916398) = 49.49871336^o$. I am asking this as arctan $(\frac \pi{2}) = \infty$. Am referring to https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/Arctan_Calculator.html, that is giving a valid angle for arctan $(\frac \pi{2}) $ too of $57.51836341^o$.

Comment: Based on your last stmt. in chatroom: 
"$\arctan$ give you result between $-\frac{\pi}2$ and $\frac{\pi}2$  
$\arctan(\frac{\pi}2)$ is finite". $arctan(\frac{\pi}2)\approx 57^o$ & not $90^o$. I agree that radians/angle is the domain (<del>not range</del>) for $\tan()$ & range (<del>not, domain</del>) for $\arctan()$. So, if give $\frac{\pi}2$ as argument to $\arctan()$, it will take it just as any value for $x$. I mean that probably there is no use directly for $\arctan$ then.

Comment: By "no use directly for $\arctan$", I meant that for problem that asks to find if there exists any element in set $(u-\epsilon,u]$ where $u\gt s$ is any upper bound for fn : $S_4 = \{arctan(x)\,: x\in \mathbb{R}\}$, & given $\epsilon=0.5, 0.1, 0.05$; are leading for chosen value of $u=\frac{\pi}2 +.1$ to intervals $((\frac{\pi}2+.1)-0.5, \frac{\pi}2], ((\frac{\pi}2+.1)-0.1, \frac{\pi}2], ((\frac{\pi}2+.1)-0.05, \frac{\pi}2]$. But, these range values are in a limited range only. This adds none to problem, & only interesting part is that upper closed bound is not in the set $S_4$.

Comment: I mean that can easily state that the elements of $S_4$ for real $x$ (positive, or negative) that will lie in the three (above stted) range intervals are $((\frac{\pi}2-0.4), \frac{\pi}2), (\frac{\pi}2, \frac{\pi}2) = \emptyset, ((\frac{\pi}2+.0.05), \frac{\pi}2)=\emptyset$. The only interesting thing is added by the fact that the upper bound is not in the set of values taken by $\arctan(x)$.

Comment: A real issue : I want to compute the value of $\tan((\frac{\pi}{2}+0.1)-0.5 \approx 1.1707963267948966192313216916398)$ & get a very small value of $2.36522242$ only. So, this is the value of ordinate obtained on the $y$-axis.

Comment: Please vet the part of post related to $S_5$. Have edited & corrected it. I realized the error for the next post, that uses the same sets. If this is wrong, then next would be too, affecting two posts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please vet my post's $S_5$ in both questions. The new post will be posted after your vetting. I am sorry but so much error is creeping in, that am scared.

Comment: Please vet my post at : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3215520/424260.